# How do I enable Link Preview Images for a Jekyll Website?

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

I am looking for a way to display an image when the link is posted on Twitter, Discord, etc.

There is a spot for the text but I am not aware of a place for an image.

I am expecting an image to display like this:

---

[image: Twitter Preview #1]

### This is what I am getting:

[image: Twitter Preview #2]

The description text was changed in `config.yml` so is there a parameter for the image there also?

I am unaware of how to make the link preview image appear. Think it might be in the `config.yml` file.

Answer (score 1):

The description is the description from the `head` of [your website](https://github.com/Nazchanel/eshaniyer.tech).

> `<meta property="og:description" content="This is the website that hosts Eshan Iyer’s portfolio and resume as well as many projects that he has created.">`

The image is not the favicon as I thought but another meta tag:

> `<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg">`

See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/summary-card-with-large-image

To show it, you need to modify/customize the head file for the minimal theme, either in [head.html](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/head.html) or in [custom-head.html](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/custom-head.html).

I'd try head.html first:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/86535168?v=4">
  ...
  
</head>
```

Comment: Will this work for any website or application that supports link previews?

Comment: This is pretty twitter-specific :)

Comment: I would like something that is universal but I will try this to see if it is.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try to add  `<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />` and `<meta name="twitter:card" content="app">`

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/86535168?v=4">
  ...
  
</head>
```

and

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="twitter:card" content="app">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/86535168?v=4">
  ...
  
</head>
```

this will resolve your problem, Twitter may take some time to redirect before posting on Twitter validate your link [here](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) 2-3 times